# Bulk email stuck at 'Running'

Tags: civimail, drupal

I have a bulk mailing to 264 addressees which gets stuck at 'Running'. The first time it sent many duplicate emails to 7 users but never made any further progress so was cancelled. It was resubmitted and made even less progress & was cancelled after an hour. The problem seems to be a lock failure - traceback is [here](https://pastebin.com/hbFqsVE9)  This is using the builtin PHP mail() facility which when tested in Administer/Settings/Outbound (Sendmail/SMTP) works fine. This is on a shared host, by the way. Any advice on how to debug this, please?